# Combining multiple JOINS(inner and Left)into one Select

Tags: mysql

My problem is that i have 4 tables, that i want to combine. Table1 has Tickets, Table2 with users, Table 3 with admins and Table4 with files. My Select was woring great when i had only 3 tables, without files, my select back then was something like this

```
SELECT 
      Table1.TicketNumber, 
      Count(Table1.TicketNumber) as "number of tickets",
      Table2.UserName,
      Table3.AdminName

FROM  Table1
      inner join 
      table2 on table1.ID_U=table2.ID
      inner join 
      table3 on table1.ID_A=table3.ID

GROUP BY Table1.TicketNumber
```

Then i decided to add to my select another table(Table4), from which i would sum number of files for corresponding Ticket, and my Select is something like this:

```
SELECT 
      Table1.TicketNumber ,
      Table1.count, 
      Table4.count 
FROM
      ( SELECT TicketNumber,
                count(*) AS count 
        FROM Table1 
        GROUP BY TicketNumber
      )Table1

      LEFT JOIN

      ( SELECT TickerNumber, 
               count(*) as count 
        FROM Table2
        GROUP BY TicketNumber
       ) Table2 ON Table1.Name=Table2.Name
```

My problem is when i try to in somehow merge these two selects to get all that i want, i get syntax error in my INNER JOIN   that Table1.ID_U doesnt exist.

Here is simplified struct of my Tables

```
Table1                                             Table 2/3
+----+--------------+------+------+----------+     +----+----------------+
| ID | TicketNumber | ID_U | ID_A | SomeData |     | ID | User/Admin Name|
+----+--------------+------+------+----------+     +----+----------------+
|  0 | T001         |    1 |    1 | blah     |     |  0 | Name           |
|  1 | T002         |    2 |    3 | blah     |     |  1 | Name           |
|  2 | T002         |    2 |    3 | blah     |     |  2 | Name           |
|  3 | T003         |    2 |    2 | blah     |     |  3 | Name           |
|  4 | T004         |    3 |    1 | blah     |     |  4 | Name           |
+----+--------------+------+------+----------+     +----+----------------+
My Table4
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | TicketName | FileName |
+----+------------+----------+
|  0 | T002       | Name     |
|  1 | T002       | Name     |
|  2 | T003       | Name     |
|  3 | T004       | Name     |
|  4 | T007       | Name     |
+----+------------+----------+
```

My goal is to reach Select that looks like this

```
+----+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| ID | TicketNumber | HowManyTickets | HowManyFiles |   User   |   Admin   |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|  0 | T001         |              1 |            0 | UserName | AdminName |
|  1 | T002         |              2 |            2 | UserName | AdminName |
|  2 | T003         |              1 |            1 | UserName | AdminName |
|  3 | T004         |              5 |            1 | UserName | AdminName |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

Unfortunaly all i am capable of doing is either getting

> TicketNumber, HowManyTickets, HowManyFiles,

or

> TicketNumber, HowManyTickets, User, Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your result `ID` is generated since its not anymore the same to your `TicketID`.

Here's my suggestion, using `row_number()` to generate the ID, then use `sum()` aggregation function to group your ticketNumber. `left join` will give you 0 result on your `Ticket T001`.

```
select row_number() over (order by t1.TicketNumber) as ID
    , t1.TicketNumber
    , sum(case when coalesce(t1.TicketNumber, '') = '' then 0 else 1 end) as HowManyTickets
    , coalesce(t4.numFiles, 0) as HowManyFiles 
    , t2.Name as USER
    , t3.Name as Admin
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID_U
left join table3 t3 on t3.ID = t1.ID_A
left join 
    (select count(1) as numFiles, TicketNumber from table4 group by TicketNumber) t4 on t4.TicketNumber = t1.TicketNumber
group by t1.TicketNumber, t4.numFiles
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and is much simpler. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, not really, for some reason sometimes it takes howManyFiles number and places it inside HowManyTickets, any clue why is that happening? For example i got in my database only one record with TicketNumber T005 but 4 images in Table 4 for this number, and my HowManyTickets show the number 4

Comment: @MariuszRakoczy, we can also use sum for How Many tickets, i updated the answer

Comment: Seems to me like this doesnt do the trick, when i use `left join table4 t4 on t4.TicketNumber =t1.TicketNumber` My HowManyTickets and HowManyFiles is the same, for example i got 3 tickets and 2 files for one TicketNumber, then both of them show the result of 6, like this would multiply itself

Comment: @MariuszRakoczy, seems we need a subquery for t4

Comment: I can't get this subquery right, how do we make one? EDIT: hold on i might just get this working, gonna update in a minute

Comment: Haven't noticed by commenting you also updated your answer and tried on my own using websites on how to make subqueries, i managed to make it work by inserting (select ...) inside Select just after 'howmanytickets' and haven't tried this in left join. Anyway, thank you so much for your time, i wouldn't be able to handle this on my own

Comment: @MariuszRakoczy, here's the dbfiddle i used https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=rriMaMnGdg